# How can I synchronize closures?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

How can I synchronize closures?

I have this code:

```
    private func getWeather(parameters: [String : Any],  failure: ((String) -> Void)? = nil ,completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {

        for _ in 0...10 {

            RequestManager.sharedInstance.request(url: baseURL, parameters: parameters, completion:  { (result) in
                if JSON.parse(result)["name"].string == nil {
                    failure?("Something went wrong. Please, try again later")
                } else {
                    let weatherModel: WeatherModel = WeatherModel(json: JSON.parse(result))
                }
            })
        }
        completion?()

    }
```

In my code, completion?() will call, not when all requests will ended
And I need call completion?() when all requests will ended. Ho can I do it?

Comment: Research `DispatchGroup`.

Comment: [Here is a great tutorial](https://dispatchswift.com/introduction-to-dispatch-group-a5cf9d61ff4f)

Comment: Or have a look on nsoperation(queue) and setup dependencies

Comment: @vikingosegundo The problem with trying to use dependent operations in this case is that the operations kick off their own async operation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since the currently accepted answer isn't correct, here is a version that properly uses a `DispatchGroup`.

```
private func getWeather(parameters: [String : Any],  failure: ((String) -> Void)? = nil ,completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    for _ in 0...10 {
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        RequestManager.sharedInstance.request(url: baseURL, parameters: parameters) { result in
            if JSON.parse(result)["name"].string == nil {
                failure?("Something went wrong. Please, try again later")
            } else {
                let weatherModel: WeatherModel = WeatherModel(json: JSON.parse(result))
            }
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
    }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        completion?()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will start using this, and delete my accepted answer... or I can't delete an accepted answer...

Comment: Oh, @rmaddy, Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @rmaddy I made a meta post about the scenario if you want to contribute. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346284/why-cant-i-delete-an-accepted-answer-posted-by-myself

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is just to count completed calls.

```
private func getWeather(parameters: [String : Any],  failure: ((String) -> Void)? = nil ,completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    let numCalls = 11;
    var completedCalls = 0;

    for _ in 0..<numCalls {

        RequestManager.sharedInstance.request(url: baseURL, parameters: parameters, completion:  { (result) in
            if JSON.parse(result)["name"].string == nil {
                failure?("Something went wrong. Please, try again later")
            } else {
                let weatherModel: WeatherModel = WeatherModel(json: JSON.parse(result))
            }
            completedCalls += 1
            if completedCalls == numCalls {
                completion?()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Your completion callback runs when each request ends. Making each of your completion callbacks update a value in its enclosing scope allows you to keep track of how many requests have ended. When all the requests you expect have ended, you call `completion?()`.

Comment: yeah, It is obvious)) But I think that there is some elegant solution :-)

Comment: You could try creating a function which abstracts this call-counting pattern. It would take which request to make and how many times to make it, or a list of requests.

Comment: I would definitely recommend using DispatchGroup over this.